# How can I ask for an algorithm on Stack Overflow?

Tags: discussion, close-reasons, closed-questions

I'm wondering why [my question](//stackoverflow.com/questions/25105599/algorithm-for-finding-similar-images-using-an-index) was set on hold/closed.

For sure I read the explanation and after a while I also found [the page](//stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) from which the explanation was copied from.

But it's my opinion that in this case, this is just paragraph hunting.

The problem I have, finding an algorithm with the described behaviour is very hard to do since there are lots of algorithms and projects out there which are able to compare images, but none of which I already found was able to to this using indexes. all of them scale extremely badly to bigger numbers of files. Unfortunately, it's almost impossible to change a simple image comparing algorithm to an index based one, this would be like comparing hashes of passwords and say if they are similar but not equal.

I see in the explanation of Stack Overflow that you want to avoid spamming. I agree this is a good intention. But in this case it's not just "help me finding a browser" or "which programming language is the best for me". It is a well defined problem of which I think a lot of other people might also be interested in it. And I don't think there will come more than two answers in total, so how can this thread become a spam problem?

I also considered publishing my question on another page of Stack Overflow but since my problem is heavily focused on programming I don't think it belongs to [Software Recommendations](//softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/) or [Computer Science](//cs.stackexchange.com/) but the first of them seems to be more for end-user-software and the latter is about the algorithm itself and not about the implementations of it.

Comment: You list software to compare images. Rather than ask "what did they use", have you tried search for algorithms themselves? Did you evaluate them? What did you find? The latter process might lead to a good on-topic question.

Comment: If you had actually asked for an algorithm, your question might have worked.  But it appears to me that you're asking for an external resource of some kind; you're even holding up other external resources for comparison purposes.  We don't do that here; [that's what Google is for](https://www.google.com/#q=algorithms%20to%20detect%20similar%20images).

Comment: @Bart I found things like http://www.phash.org/demo/ and I found answers like those in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8644960/java-library-to-compare-image-similarity - all of them are NOT using indexes :-(

Comment: See here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/75891/algorithm-for-finding-similar-images

Comment: Don't discount academic research. I'd extend my search to include such sources. Unless you have a specific definition of on "index", I'd say it's essentially nothing  more than one or more results of various algorithms giving you a signature. Feature detection, colour signatures, etc. They are probably more of an implementation detail than a real algorithmic requirement for similarity.

Comment: @Daniel - Perhaps you should try [Software Recommendations Stack Exchange](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/). Once you discover which is "best", then investigate the algorithm. Once you know the algorithm, visit Stack Overflow for help with the implementation. Don't get upset because Stack Overflow is *not* one-stop shopping. Its just the way it is. I often ask related questions on Super User, Web Apps and Server Fault. Sometimes the related questions go unanswered, but that's the way it is.

Comment: @jww Thanks. This is the most constructive answer so far.

Answer (score 20):

I'm no mod but, based on experience, asking *about* an algorithm is on-topic while asking *for* an algorithm is off-topic. As noted, asking *for* an algorithm often produces list-type answers and discussions of merit, often without proper context.

When I say asking *about* an algorithm, I mean inquiring about an algorithm's behavior---will it stay O(f(n)) given condition x/will O(g(n)) space complexity bother me if I do y---they tend to produce answers grounded in fact rather than opinion. I believe they will fall under "a specific programming problem" and "a software algorithm" bullets of our [on-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) criteria.

There are probably better examples of this with more upvotes but here's [an algorithm question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7088678/4-connected-vs-8-connected-in-connected-component-labeling-what-is-are-the-meri) I asked years ago which I believe illustrates my point.

Comment: Right.  Asking about an algorithm - "I'm designing an algorithm to do X, and here's my work so far.  I can't figure out how to do Y part of X" - fine.  "Should I use sync sort or quick sort for this process", probably okay if it has an objective answer.  But asking for either a) a link to an algorithm that exists somewhere else, or b) asking someone to write an algorithm for you (assuming this has some complexity to it) would not be.

Comment: @Joe Does asking if "that kind of algorithm exist" without asking for a complete list is off or on topic ?

Comment: I would say that's off topic, because it's just a yes-no question that the answer doesn't help anyone (ie, a complete answer is 'yes') but I think it's somewhat controversial (and a gray area).  That's been discussed before, you'll have to look for where.

Answer (score -2):

I agree that your question is legitimate, there is nothing to say about that....

but SO is made to avoid these kind of "forum-like" discussions... you might be better off using :http://forums.codeguru.com/forumdisplay.php?65-Algorithms-Data-Structures or some similar forum

Comment: "Where is my dog?" is also a legitimate question. Doesn't make it on-topic or suitable.

Comment: what do you mean with forum-like discussion?

Comment: @oded: He means that it's an actual (programming) question.  Doesn't necessarily make it on-topic.

Comment: @DanielAlder: He means like a forum.  Have you ever tried to get a good answer from a forum?  They are as rare as four-leaf clovers.

Comment: @oded my whole message says the question is legitimate but NOT for SO..... and you basically answer with "legitimate != good for SO"... I'm trying to understand what you mean here

Comment: @DanielAlder more of an opinion based, tool-search.  In a forum you look at people's opinions more than a "be all end all" solution.  I'm not saying it's going to be EASY to get a correct answer from a forum, but SO is definitely not the place for this kind of question

Comment: @Julldar Ok I see. It's just that I wasn't asking for opinions. I'm only asking for names and/or links

Comment: @danielAlder yeah but I think more than one tool actually satisfies your question (I never did heavy image analysis, but I assume more than one library/third party tool tackled the problem), so in the end it might be a question of "which tool do YOU prefer?" which shouldn't be on SO....   I get your frustration though :(  Best of luck in your search ^^

Comment: @Julldar I clearly asked for an index capable algorithm. This just disqualifies all the answers, so all I prefer is a valid answer...